# How to iterate DataFrame column of stock symbols and add a column with the stock price?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a `dataframe` w/ the index column being stock symbols. My question is, how do I loop through the list of stock symbols and add a column to the `dataframe` with the stock price for each symbol?

Here is where my mind went...

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import pandas.io.data as web
import datetime as dt

start = '2005-01-01'
end = dt.datetime.today()

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    df['Price'] = web.DataReader(df['Symbol'], 'yahoo', start, end)
```

my dataframe looks like this...

```
In [1]: %run screen.py
   symbol core
16    LEA    1
17     GT    1
18    TEN    1
19   HELE    1
20    CTB    1
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the original df?

Comment: I'm pulling a list of 1,500 stock symbols from a CSV file. How can I add a snippet of that into the question? I have seen other people do it, but I am embarrassed I don't know how

Comment: One easy way is to paste the result of `print(df.head())` in your question. Then people can easily get the data in a dataframe using `pd.read_clipboard()`.

Comment: How do you copy/paste from iPython in the terminal?

Comment: right click paste on Linux, hover by pushing right click on Winz

Comment: "add a column to the dataframe with the stock price": Stock price as of when?

Comment: It doesn't matter when, it can be most recent stock price. I just want to know how to pass the symbol into web.DataReader

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The DataReader returns a series of prices, so I've just requested the closing price over the last few days.  I then use `.iloc[-1, :]` to take all prices on the last row which would be the most recent close.

```
today = dt.date.today()
prices = web.DataReader(df.symbol, 'yahoo', 
                        start=today + dt.timedelta(-5), end=today)['Close'].iloc[-1, :]
```

You now need to convert the prices to a DataFrame in order to merge it to your original dataframe:

```
prices = pd.DataFrame(prices)
close_date = prices.columns[0]
prices.columns = ['closing_price']
df = df.merge(prices, how='left', left_on='symbol', right_index=True)
df['close date'] = close_date

>>> df
  symbol  core  closing_price close date
0    LEA     1     113.150002 2015-10-06
1     GT     1      30.389999 2015-10-06
2    TEN     1      47.900002 2015-10-06
3    HLE     1      77.950000 2015-10-06
4    CTB     1      39.840000 2015-10-06
```